# transfer from c# to excel with multiple sheets

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary, export, xls

I have a few different dictionaries with different categories of information and I need to output them all into an xls or csv file with multiple spreadsheets. Currently, I have to download each excel file for a specific date range individually and then copy and paste them together so they're on different sheets of the same file. Is there any way to download all of them together in one document? Currently, I use the following code to output their files:

```
 writeCsvToStream(
     organize.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value as IacTransmittal), writer
 );
 ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", ms.Length.ToString());
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
 ms.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);

 Response.End();
```

where `writeCsvToStream` just creates the text for the individual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to learning a new library, I highly recommend [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

I'm making a few assumptions here since you didn't post much code to translate, but an example of usage may look like this:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;

public static void WriteXlsOutput(Dictionary<string, IacTransmittal> collection) //accepting one dictionary as a parameter
{
    using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream("Example.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (ExcelPackage ePackage = new ExcelPackage(outFile))
        {
            //group the collection by date property on your class
            foreach (IGrouping<DateTime, IacTransmittal> collectionByDate in collection
                .OrderBy(i => i.Value.Date.Date)
                .GroupBy(i => i.Value.Date.Date)) //assuming the property is named Date, using Date property of DateTIme so we only create new worksheets for individual days
            {
                ExcelWorksheet eWorksheet = ePackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(collectionByDate.Key.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")); //add a new worksheet for each unique day

                Type iacType = typeof(IacTransmittal);
                PropertyInfo[] iacProperties = iacType.GetProperties();
                int colCount = iacProperties.Count(); //number of properties determines how many columns we need
                //set column headers based on properties on your class
                for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                {
                    eWorksheet.Cells[1, col].Value = iacProperties[col - 1].Name ; //assign the value of the cell to the name of the property
                }

                int rowCounter = 2;

                foreach (IacTransmittal iacInfo in collectionByDate) //iterate over each instance of this class in this igrouping
                {
                    int interiorColCount = 1;
                    foreach (PropertyInfo iacProp in iacProperties) //iterate over properties on the class
                    {
                        eWorksheet.Cells[rowCounter, interiorColCount].Value = iacProp.GetValue(iacInfo, null); //assign cell values by getting the value of each property in the class
                        interiorColCount++;
                    }
                    rowCounter++;
                }
            }
            ePackage.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some different options you could use.

- ADO.NET Excel driver - with this API you can populate data into Excel documents using SQL style syntax. Each worksheet in the workbook is a table, each column header in a worksheet is a column in that table etc.

Here is a code project article on the exporting to Excel using ADO.NET:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567155/Work-with-MS-Excel-and-ADO-NET

The ADO.NET approach is safe to use in a multi-user, web app environment.

- Use OpenXML to export the data
  OpenXML is a schema definition for different types of documents and the later versions of Excel (the ones that use .xlsx, .xlsm etc. instead of just .xls) use this format for the documents. The OpenXML schema is huge and somewhat cumbersome, however you can do pretty much anything with it.

Here is a code project article on exporting data to Excel using OpenXML:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692121/Csharp-Export-data-to-Excel-using-OpenXML-librarie

The OpenXML approach is safe to use in a multi-user, web app environment.

- A third approach is to use COM automation which is the same as programmatically running an instance of the Excel desktop application and using COM to control the actions of that instance.

Here is an article on that topic:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Note that this third approach (office automation) is *not* safe in a multi-user, web app environment. I.e. it should not be used on a server, only from standalone desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas! I was eventually able to figure out the following

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook = null;
Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet = null;

ExcelApp.Visible = true;
ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

List<string> SheetNames = new List<string>() 
    { "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7"};

string [] headers = new string [] 
    { "Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4", "Field 5" };

for (int i = 0; i < SheetNames.Count; i++)
    ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(); //Adding New sheet in Excel Workbook

for (int k = 0; k < SheetNames.Count; k++ )
{
    int r = 1; // Initialize Excel Row Start Position  = 1

    ExcelWorkSheet = ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets[k + 1];
    //Writing Columns Name in Excel Sheet
    for (int col = 1; col < headers.Length + 1; col++)
        ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = headers[col - 1];
    r++;
    switch (k)
    {
        case 0:
            foreach (var kvp in Sheet1)
            {
                ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, 1] = kvp.Value.Field1;
                ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, 2] = kvp.Value.Field2;
                ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, 3] = kvp.Value.Field3;
                ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, 4] = kvp.Value.Field4;
                ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, 5] = kvp.Value.Field5;
                r++;
            }
            break;

    }
    ExcelWorkSheet.Name = SheetNames[k];//Renaming the ExcelSheets
}

//Activate the first worksheet by default.
((Excel.Worksheet)ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Activate();

//Save As the excel file.
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(@"out_My_Book1.xls");
```